# Drawing Bitmap onto ImageButton

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, android-button, android-drawable

I'm working on a game at the moment and have run into something I can't figure out. I have a list of ImageButtons that I'm iterating over and drawing a Bitmap on each of them. The Bitmap itself is drawing fine, however I also want to draw rectangles onto these Bitmaps.

The relevant code (I can post more if this isn't enough):

```
for (int i = 1; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
        ImageButton button = (ImageButton) group.getChildAt(i);
        Bitmap bitmap = getBackgroundImage();
        bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        for (int j = 0; j < obstacles.get(i - 1).size(); j++) {
            Obstacle o = obstacles.get(i - 1).get(j);
            canvas.drawRect((float) o.getXLower(), (float) o.getYLower(),
                    (float) o.getXUpper(), (float) o.getYUpper(), paint);
        }

        Drawable background = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);

        button.setBackground(background);
    }
```

The Bitmap itself is appearing on the buttons, however the rectangles that I want drawn aren't being drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Would you call

```
ImageButton.setImageBitmap(Bitmap)
```

instead?